Consents UX Design
I need to have 3 consents of the page I'm developing. How can I show these prompts in a fitting UX design?
I tried adding each consents headings in boxes along with a button. Clicking the button will trigger a pop up where we can see the consent and accept or decline it. This approach involves too many clicks.
Is there a better way to present this to the user?

Consents for what exactly, cookies maybe?

not kind of  Cookies, our app has to let the user we are keeping the personal and other info. the consent info will be too lengthy, user has to read.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"I'm faced with the challenge of elegantly showcasing three consents on a single page through UX design. My initial attempt involved placing each consent's heading in separate boxes alongside a button. However, clicking on each button triggered a pop-up displaying the full consent, resulting in too many clicks for users. Are there alternative methods to present these consents that streamline the user experience?"

Can you please share an image of what these consents look like.

Can user consent to two of it and not consent to the one and still proceed? Would you be able to add your current direction as an edit to the question above? And also add maximum information for us in it too? We will be able to solve this together!

There are so many examples out there that have buttons for consent with a text what it is for. Also a lot of them have an accept all/none option to reduce clicks. Can you explain why you have trouble designing this?

I think you need to have a hierarchy of "Read text", "Accept text" and "Decline text" and allow the user to decide what to do and in which order.
What about something like this?
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Consent 1            [Read more] [Accept] [Decline] |
| Maybe show some lines of the text if there is       |
| enough space available.                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Consent 2            [Read more] [Accept] [Decline] |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Consent 3            [Read more] [Accept] [Decline]^|
| You can either show the full text on clicking the | |
| "read more" button. Or you show the full text if  | |
| clicking (tapping) somewhere on this area and use | |
| a scrollable area if needed.                      |v|
+-----------------------------------------------------+

Clicking [Accept] or [Decline] can show an indicator like "pressed down state" or showing a "tick" or "X" symbol etc.
If all three choices are made, the screen flow continues to the next step.
